# Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: UInt16 and UInt32

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2, landsat-8

What are the possible reasons for this error?

> Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent
> types: UInt16 and UInt32

This is the code:

```
Map.addLayer(PuntoQuellaveco1);
Map.addLayer(operaciones);
Map.addLayer(Abast);


 var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
 .filterBounds(PuntoQuellaveco1)
 .filterDate('2016-07-01','2016-08-31')
 .sort('CLOUD_COVER', false);

var conteo = image.size();
print('conteo de imágenes', conteo);

var mejorImagen = ee.Image(image.sort('CLOUD_COVER').first());

print('La primera con menos nubosidad', mejorImagen);

Map.addLayer(mejorImagen, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 3000}, 'image');

var fechaAdquirida = mejorImagen.get('DATE_ACQUIRED');

print('Fecha adquirida', fechaAdquirida);


 Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mejorImagen,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 10,
  region: Abast
   });
```

The variables are already created, They just can't be copied because of this:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

If you have a look at Sentinel 2 bands you'll find that all bands are type `unsigned int 16` except for `QA20` that is `unsigned int 32`, that band is causing the issue.

[image: S2 bands]

You can solve it in different ways, but I post here what I think is what you need:

```js
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
              .filterBounds(PuntoQuellaveco1)
              .filterDate('2016-07-01','2016-08-31')
              .sort('CLOUD_COVER', false);

var conteo = image.size();
print('conteo de imágenes', conteo);

var mejorImagen = ee.Image(image.sort('CLOUD_COVER').first());

print('La primera con menos nubosidad', mejorImagen);

Map.addLayer(mejorImagen, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 3000}, 'image');

var fechaAdquirida = mejorImagen.get('DATE_ACQUIRED');

print('Fecha adquirida', fechaAdquirida);

// Keep only 'B' bands
// Me quedo solo con las bandas 'B'
mejorImagen = mejorImagen.select('B.+')

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mejorImagen,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 10,
  region: Abast
   });
```

Or you could make `QA20` and `unsigned int 16` to match the others:

```js
// Cast band's types to uint16
// Transformo los tipos de dato de las bandas a uint16
mejorImagen = mejorImagen.toUint16()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2021-08-17', '2021-08-19')
                  .select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2'])
                  .filterBounds(LS);
```

After specifying the required bands, there are no issues.